# [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene: crashes game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I get the following error report after my game crashes on startup.

When I try to replace the scene using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCZoomFlipXTransition transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[MainMenu node]]];
```

I get the error and it crashes the app.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds for empty array'

What is the cause of this, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: did you `#import MainMenu.h`?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the first scene you are loading you need to use runWithScene not replaceScene.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[MainMenu scene]];
```

Comment: Its not. I run a splash screen first, and I am trying to replace the splash screen with the Main Menu scene.

Comment: Have you ran the debugger? What does the stack tell you? What version of cocos2d are you using? Have you checked coco2D site to see if this is a known issue for the version you are using?

Comment: What I dont get is that I can call this scene (MainMenu) as the first scene using runWithScene. When I replace with it, it crashes. Maybe it is where I am calling it or how I am calling it.

Comment: I think it was because I was calling it in the init method, so their was no scene to replace yet.

Comment: Great so it was because there was no scene. Glad you found a fix!